# What this JavaScript function method called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am quite interested when I run this simple function

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var widthValue = that.width();

    console.log(widthValue + 'px');
});
```

It works when I start resizing my browser window.

But when I do this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var widthValue = that.width();

    console.log(widthValue + 'px');
}).resize();
```

It acts like `load();`. I added `resize()` at the end.

What is this called? Not sure I understand why and how this works.

Comment: You simply bind a function to an event then trigger that event.

Comment: it does not act like `load` because it will instantly trigger that function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technique is called *Chaining*.

It boils down to a function returning `this` at the end, so you can call another method of the same object by chaining the method calls one after the other.

```
var foo = {
  count: 0,
  up: function () { this.count++; return this; },
  show: function () { alert(this.count); return this; }
}

foo.show().up().show().up().up().show();
```

In this particular example, the `resize` method is overloaded. If you give it a function argument then it will bind that function as an event handler. If you call it without arguments, then it will trigger that event instead.

Answer (score 0):

With the 2nd case, you are invoking or triggering the `resize` event.